# When To Implement IUnknown in a class

Tags: c++, com, iunknown

I am writing a C++ class that consumes at least one COM interface from the Windows API.  Obviously, when consuming these objects inside of the class I would need to properly call `AddRef()` and `Release()`.

My question is...do I need to additionally implement `IUnknown` in the C++ class itself?  My understanding is that I would only need to do that if the interface I was using was performing asynchronous operations or callbacks.  In that case you would need to make sure that the C++ class itself was still "alive" when the asynchronous operation or callback completed.  is this correct?

For clarification (and per Hans' comment) the specific interface I am interested in is `IMFSourceReader`(Windows Media Foundation).  This interface defaults to synchronous mode.  So again, if I understand this correctly, I would only need to implement `IUnknown` in my C++ class if I chose instead to use it in asynchronous mode.  Otherwise calls to `IMFSourceReader->AddRef()` or `IMFSourceReader->Release` would be sufficient.

If, however, I chose to use `IMFSourceReader` in asynchronous mode, that requires `IMFSourceReaderCallback` interface, which in itself inherits `IUnknown`.  In that case I'd have to implement it in the class.

Is my understanding correct?  I'm still in the early stages of writing the implementation so I don't really have example code to share.  At this point I'm just trying to get the very basic structure of my class nailed down.

Comment: Have you read [How IUnknown Works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388915(v=vs.85).aspx) already?

Comment: If it is a COM interface implemented by Windows then clearly you do not need to ask such a vague question.  Don't ask for the manual, show what you are trying to do.

Comment: A tip: It's a good idea implementing a smart pointer like wrapper class to do the `AddRef()` and `Release()` calls properly (see [here](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00045.html) for reference).

Comment: @user0042:  Yes, smart pointers are useful. However, I'm trying to fully understand the underlying concepts and not just have the smart pointers hide all of the implementation for me

Comment: @MichaelBuckman You probably misunderstood. YOU have to implement the smart pointer then (unless using some Microsoft standard stuff dong that). The Loki policy is just a way how you could provide such implementation properly and in a safe way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only implement IUnknown if you are yourself implementing a COM object, merely consuming COM does not require that you implement IUnknown.

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I thought that was the case, but my study of COM is still in its infancy, so I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Just to add to that  If the COM object you are consuming also exposes events (e.g. via IConnectionPointContainer) and you want to subscribe to those events with an event sink, you will end up being forced to implement a COM object (your event sink) in order to do so.